# Add solution or selected project to SVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I haven't used SVN for quite awhile and now I need to add my project/solution to SVN in order to keep track of changes.

When I right click on the solution node in Visual Studio 2013, there are 2 options for me:

1. Add soluction to SVN
2. Add selected project to SVN.

My initial thought was I'd like to add all things under this solution to SVN, so I chose option 1.
But since then, I found that only the Visual Studio solution file has a SVN enabled tick in font of it, but for the rest of other files(.proj, .js, .cs, .html, .css etc.) they have no SVN enabled tick/icon/whatever the name is in front of them. So I guess they are not added into the SVN repository.

So my question is: what is the proper way to add my entire solution(not just solution file) into SVN?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 will work when there's a common root. This means a structure like:

```
Path\foo.sln
Path\project\project.csproj
Path\project\image.jpg
```

When there's no common root, it cannot be automatically created right now.

Comment: You are probably right, as my sln file was located in a different folder.